# $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp}$ and $(W_1\cap W_2)^{\perp}$ in terms of $W_1$ and $W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$, and let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces. Express $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp}$ in terms of $W_1^{\perp}$ and $W_2^{\perp}$. Also, express $(W_1\cap W_2)^{\perp}$ in terms of $W_1^{\perp}$ and $W_2^{\perp}$.

I have no idea what this exercise is asking. Remark: I am self-studying and I do not have solutions.

**Questions**:

What am I supposed to prove? How should I prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408973/w-1-perp-w-2-perp-w-1-cap-w-2-perp-can-a-set-be-a-function-can-tw?rq=1) for the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove: $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp}=W_1^\perp\cap W_2^\perp.$

$W_1,W_2\subset W_1+W_2,$ and we know $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp} \subset W_1^{\perp},W_2^{\perp}$

So we get: $$(W_1+W_2)^{\perp} \subset W_1^{\perp}\cap W_2^{\perp}$$

In the other direction,

Let $v\in W_1^{\perp}\cap W_2^{\perp},$ so for every $w_1+w_2 \in W_1 + W_2:$

$$\langle v,w_1+w_2 \rangle=\langle v,w_1\rangle+\langle v,w_2\rangle=0$$

Hence, $v\in (W_1+W_2)^{\perp}.$

Comment: $\langle v,w_1\rangle$+$\langle v,w_2\rangle=0$? Why is it zero $v$ could still belong to $W_1$?

Comment: @PedroGomes $v\in W_1^{\perp},$ how could it belong to $W_1?$

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? I see $v$ can be in $W_1$ or in $W_2$, so the individual inner products would not be zero, right?

Comment: @PedroGomes $v$ is in both $W_1^{\perp}$ and $W_2^{\perp}$, that's the definition of intersection.

Comment: How do you know that $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp} \subset W_1^{\perp}\cap W_2^{\perp}$ keeps the inequality $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp} \subset W_1^{\perp},W_2^{\perp}$, if  $W_1^{\perp},W_2^{\perp}\subset W_1^{\perp}\cap W_2^{\perp}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp}=W_1^\perp\cap W_2^\perp$; 
$(W_1\bigcap W_2)^{\perp}=W_1^\perp +W_2^\perp$.

Comment: Am I supposed to prove that? How do I prove it?

Comment: Try yourself! then you'll benefit from 'exercise'.

Comment: or show some effort.

Comment: Main thing to use in a proof (this one, and most others from elementary courses) is the definitions.  Here, definition of $\perp$ and of $+$ and of $\cap$.  The idea is: by thinking about this, you become familiar with the definitions.  Unfortunately, reading Itay4's proof will help you much less than that.

Comment: @GEdgar Check out this proof of mine please. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359794/w-1-bigcap-w-2-perp-w-1-perpw-2-perp-with-functionals