# $({W_1\bigcap W_2})^\perp=W_1^\perp+W_2^\perp$ with functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$, and let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces. Express $(W_1+W_2)^{\perp}$ in terms of $W_1^{\perp}$ and $W_2^{\perp}$. Also, express $(W_1\cap W_2)^{\perp}$ in terms of $W_1^{\perp}$ and $W_2^{\perp}$.

$W_1\bigcap W_2=\{x\in V:x=x_1\wedge x=x_2,x_1\in W_1,x_2\in W_2\}\\
({W_1\bigcap W_2})^\perp=\{x\in V:x\neq x_1\vee x\neq x_2,x_1\in W_1,x_2\in W_2\}\\W_1^\perp=\{x\in V:x\neq x_1:\forall x_1\in W_1\}\\W_2^\perp=\{x\in V:x\neq x_2:\forall x_2\in W_2\}\\W_1^\perp+W_2^\perp=\{x\in V:x=x_1\wedge x=x_2,x_1\in W_1,x_2\in W_2\}$

Therefore:
$({W_1\bigcap W_2})^\perp=W_1^\perp+W_2^\perp$

**Questions**:

**1)** Is this procedure right?

**2)** Since this question is on the dual space section. How can I solve it with functionals?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your definitions of $W_1^\perp$, $W_2^\perp$, etc, are incorrect.  If $S\subset V$, and $V^*$ is the set of linear functionals on $V$, then $S^\perp=\{f\in V^*:f(v)=0\text{ for all }v\in S\}$.

Comment: what has anything do with the functionals ?

Comment: So, Aweygan is right.  The first thing you have to do is look up the definition of $\perp$.  @Leth : What has to do with the functionals?  The definition of $\perp$.

Comment: @GEdgar the dual space of a vector space is more general than the space of $L(E)$.